# Node Getting JSON_PARSING_ERROR

Tags: json, node.js, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to call `GCM` notification by using POST.
The code I am using is :

```
 var jsonbody={"to": "/topics/global",
                "data": {
                "title": "TestTitle", 
                "is_background": false,
                "message": "Testmessage",
                "image": "",
                "payload": {
                    "team": "India",
                    "score": "5.6"            },
                "timestamp": "2016-12-13 16:32:05"

              }
             };

    var request = require('request');
    request.post({
    headers: {'content-type': 'application/json',
    Authorization:'key=(my key)'},
    url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
    BODY: jsonbody
    }, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) {

    console.log('failure ' + error);

    } else {

    console.log('success  '+response + 'and ' +body);

    }
    });
```

I am getting error as :

> success  [object Object]and JSON_PARSING_ERROR: Unexpected token END
>   OF FILE at position 0.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually missing something :

```
 body: JSON.stringify(jsonbody)
```

Rest all was correct.